# jQuery targeting elements with index()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

So I have two unordered lists, with the same amount of items in them. So let's assume items in unordered list #2 are all hidden. The only way to make them appear is if you click on the items in unordered list #1.

so basically

```
<ul class="list1">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list2">
  <li class="hide">item 1</li>
  <li class="hide">item 2</li>
  <li class="hide">item 3</li>
  <li class="hide">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Now the way I'm trying to accomplish this is using the `index()` method, but I'm not sure how to properly approach this code.

This is how I thought of it.

```
$('.list1').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('.list2 li').index($(this).index()).toggleClass('active');
});
```

so when you click on an line item in `.list1`, whatever the index of that line item is, is the index I want to target in `.list2`

the problem I'm having is that when I console log it, I'm getting weird index numbers. The first line item would show up as 2 rather than 0, and the index for the 2nd line item would be -1.

what am I doing wrong? a lot I'm sure.

thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Try using .eq selector with the combination of index. https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: [jQuery.index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) always returns an index, you are looking for [jQuery.eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) that reduces `[...]the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jquery [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) return index of selected element. You need to use [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector or [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to selecting element with index.

```js
$('.list1').on('click', 'li', function() {    
    $('.list2 li').eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list1">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list2">
  <li class="hide">item 1</li>
  <li class="hide">item 2</li>
  <li class="hide">item 3</li>
  <li class="hide">item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks so much for the input. this is amazing. I came across another problem unfortunately -- which is mixing .not() and .eq() together. but that's for another thread. thanks so much, this works!

Answer (score 3):

try this, this will work for you fine

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

/* in here we get the ul which the class name is list2 and get the li elements inside it and hide those first*/
ul.list2 li{
  display: none;
}



</style>

<body>

<ul class="list1">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>



</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.list1 li").click(function(){
    var theindex = $(this).index();//in here you get the index number of clicked li element inside list1 class
    $("ul.list2 li").eq(theindex).slideToggle(500);//then  in here, you show the same index li element in list2 , which we are hidden.
  });
});

 

</script>

</html>
```